Dimple js: Setting x-axis intervals when comparing annual data series
I use dimple js to compare series of values from different years, plotting each series on the same graph.
To stack the annual series over each other, the x-axis is set to use a composite "month_day" value in "mm/dd" format, like "03/27" for March 27.

The graph:
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setBounds(65, 30, 1330, 305);

var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "month_day");

//x.timePeriod = d3.time.months;    NOT WORKING
//x.timeInterval = 1;

x.tickFormat = "%m";
x.addOrderRule("month_day");

myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "daily_quantity");

myChart.addSeries("year", dimple.plot.line);
myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 500, 20, "left");
myChart.draw();

The series themselves plots correctly, but if there are few months in the x-axis, the graph shows duplicated x-axis ticks. I would like to set the x-axis, so that there is only one tick per month.
No problem is plotting series from previous years. However, if plotting only the serie of the current year 2024, the x-axis will auto-range from months "01" to "04", but prints several instances of "01", "02", "03" ticks, as there is enough space for them.
I read that one can set the timePeriod to months (x.timePeriod = d3.time.months;) but it crashes my graph.

How data are extracted (simplified code):
  SELECT 
    YEAR(date) AS year,
    CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(date),2,'0'),'/',LPAD(DAY(date),2,'0')) AS month_day,
    SUM(value) AS daily_quantity
    FROM serie_2023
    GROUP BY month_day
UNION
  SELECT 
    YEAR(date) AS year,
    CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(date),2,'0'),'/',LPAD(DAY(date),2,'0')) AS month_day,
    SUM(value) AS daily_quantity
    FROM serie_2024
    GROUP BY month_day

Of course, one could easily expose date , month, day by altering the SQL query.
